# How to fix node.js on macOS write to file permission denied error?

Tags: node.js, macos

I set up node.js to write to file on its local folder as such:

Note: I have already use `sudo chmod 755 req.txt` and `sudo chmod 755 bodyhead.txt` to set the permission of the file to be writable.

```
fs.writeFile('/req.txt', req + '\r\n!ended!\r\n', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
fs.writeFile('/bodyhead.txt', bodyhead + '\r\n!ended!\r\n', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
```

And received:

`{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/req.txt' errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'open', path: '/req.txt' }`

as well as

`{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/bodyhead.txt'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/bodyhead.txt' }`

Comment: chmod 777 path/tothe/folder or see file GetInfo and setup access permision

Answer (score 10):

> I set up node.js to write to file on its local folder...

But you're not writing to the local folder, you're writing to the root of your filesystem:

```
fs.writeFile('/req.txt', ...
              ^ root of filesystem
```

Instead, remove the leading slashes from the filenames you're trying to write:

```
fs.writeFile('req.txt', ...
fs.writeFile('bodyhead.txt', ...
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Now I gotta go clean up all these text files all over my root directory 

Comment: What if I want to update the system file for example, `/req.txt`, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @tim use that path (and, probably, root/administrator permissions)

Comment: thanks anyway, in fact, my question is how to gain the permission for `fs.writeFile(path)`

Comment: @tim that's something that needs to be handled outside of Node, eg run the script as an administrator/root user, or change the permissions on the file so regular users can write to it (although the latter might not be a good idea).

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point.

I used the second way in your comment. I `chmod 777` then `chmod 644` back, not a really good idea, and must `sudo` twice, but worked.

Comment: VSCode is written in `electron` and `node`, each time when you use it to open a system file `/etc/fstab`, when you save it, the dialog will be popped up and ask you `retry as sudo`, => after input password in the dialog, it will be saved, easy and simple, but have no idea how they achieve it.

Comment: @tim VSCode calls `sudo` itself, I imagine. There are various `sudo` packages in the NPM repository that will call a command using `sudo` (after prompting for the password), so perhaps one of those could be used to achieve what you want to do.